# Flask-SQLAlchemy: Query only certain columns, return one-to-many relationships as lists

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I query only certain columns of a table AND return fields with one-to-many relationships as lists in flask-sqlalchemy?

This is my models.py:

```
class Article(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    full_text = db.Column(db.Text)
    authors = relationship('Person',
            secondary=AssArtPer,
            backref='articles'
            )

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    full_name = db.Column(db.String(255))


AssArtPer = db.Table('ass_articles_persons',
    db.Column('art_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('articles.id')),
    db.Column('per_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('persons.id'))
    )
```

When I do

```
results = Article.query.all()
```

EDIT: I am then passing the `results` to a jinja2 template which is handing it over to a macro:

```
{% for r in results %}
    {% macros.render_article(r) %}
{% endfor %}

{% macro render_article(result) %}
    {% for a in result.authors %}
        ...render something
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Now, I would like to limit the original query to exclude the Article.full_text column because it takes very long and I can load the full text with an ajax call later. I know that I can specify certain columns to be queried with:

```
results = Article.query.with_entities(
    Article.id,
    Article.title,
    Article.authors
    ).all()
```

BUT this doesn't work. The query doesn't return anything and doesn't throw an error either.

I tried a join like so:

```
results = Article.query.join(Article.authors).with_entities(Person.id, Person.full_name)
```

...which is working fine, but I can not specify any other columns then.

How can I combine the two queries?

Comment: In your last example you're joining `Article` to `Article`. Is that intentional?

Comment: I think there are some problems with your question. For one thing, I cannot reproduce the behavior you're getting with `results = Article.query.all()` and `for name in results.authors:` -- In this case `results` is a list of objects; instances of your Article class. `results.authors` should not even work. If you take a single object from that result set, that object will have an `authors` attribute, which will probably be a list by default. What I think you want to do is define a lazy backref, so that `.authors` returns a query you can filter instead of a joined result list.

Comment: @sytech: Right, for sake of brevity I wasn't clear enough. I am actually handing `results` over to a jinja2 template, which is then passing it to a macro inside a for-loop. In the macro I then print the `results.authors` one by one. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @synul could you figure out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31901127/1216837) I think the following might work:

```
results = (
    Article.query.join(Person).
    with_entities([
        Article.id,
        Article.title,
        Article.authors,
        Person.id,
        Person.full_name]).all()
```

(Let me know if it doesn't, I have another idea.)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I'm getting an `InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got ['<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f8bf3f87650>, ... ']`

Comment: you said you had another idea?

Comment: Yes, I'll get to it this weekend!

Comment: `with_entities()` expects positional arguments, not a list.